# Restrict geoprocessing from ArcGIS Server service

Tags: arcgis-server, elevation, image

I have an Image Service up on our ArcGIS server. Its a DEM we are providing it to some of our partners. Works great and fast, but I want to turn off the ability to run tools from the service within ArcGIS programs.

I never knew that you could, but tried creating contours, exporting, it all works and I need to restrict that. The reasoning is because anyone can create copies and derivatives of this information and we don't want that. I've tried removing mensuration and metadata in the capabilities, but it doesn't appear to do anything.

Any ideas? Google has not helped me out yet.

Comment: So do you only want users using the image service for display purposes? If so maybe you can publish as a regular map service instead of an image service.

Comment: @Dowlers thats what I am thinking. Was hoping it could stay as an image service and turn off the geoprocessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by the API [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Image_Service/02r3000000q8000000/), I don't think there's a way to turn off those operations. That is the aim of an image service, to provide access to Raster data. Your best bet will be to drop the images in ArcMap and publish them as a [Map service](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Map_Service/02r3000000w2000000/). This limits the Operations which can be performed.